# Можно ли программно добавлять новые item в res/values/ids.xml?

Tags: android

Пробую программно создавать вьюхи в коде. Возникла потребность в задании определенного ID для каждой вью. Почитал вот такую статью:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216294/programmatically-add-id-to-r-id

Вот, к примеру, есть у меня

**res/values/ids.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <item name="my_edit_text_1" type="id"/>
    <item name="my_button_1" type="id"/>
    <item name="my_time_picker_1" type="id"/>

</resources>
```

Как добавить туда программно новый ID??

Answer (score 0):

Нет. Программно добавлять новые ресурсы нельзя.
ID - это число типа `int`. Вы можете использовать любое число в качестве идентификатора ваших вьюшек.

Например, определив его как константу:

```
    public static final int MY_ID = 100;
```

Вы  можете создавать вьюшки так:

```
    for (int i=0;i<1000;i++) {
            View view = new View(context);
            view.setId(MY_ID + i);
            layout.addView(view);
    }
```

И затем искать так:

```
    layout.findViewById(MY_ID+58);
```

Comment: а если у меня будет большое количество вьюшек, как мне их потом искать? И если я не буду знать точное количество этих вьюх, как я буду присваивать эти id?

Comment: Обновил ответ. Если вы не знаете точного количество вьюшек, вы можете создать переменную для хранения последнего использованного id.